# Resize a view after adding it to another view using addSubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame

i have a view called painView and after i add it with size of (40 , 40 )
i wanted to animate it when resizing to size (20 , 20)  but even without animation it doesn't change it's size after adding it , only it's location , and i am not using autolayout ..

```
dragView* paintView=[[dragView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 40,40  )];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coolPoint.png" ] ];
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, paintView.frame.size.width,paintView.frame.size.height );
        [paintView addSubview:imgView];
        [self.canvasView addSubview:paintView];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAddContentView" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        paintView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Which view isn't changing size? `paintView` or `imgView`?

Comment: both , but mainly talking about paintView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paintView has changed, but the imageView(imgView) did not. Set clipsToBounds of paintView to YES to check it. So when you change frame of paintView, change frame of imgView too.